# Is it posible to know how many users and which ones have been join my telegram group using a certain invite link in a programmatic way?

Tags: telegram, group, node-telegram-bot-api

I want to know exactly which users have being invite (and join my group) by each of my invite links.
It is important to me in order to make statistics and to give perks to the people that is getting me new followers (by referal system).

I have check telegram API docs and I can not find any way to access this information. I don't know if it is possible to search it by the invite link or to listen to updates and get the information from the new_chat_member. I have looked but I have not found.
Any idea?